# Merge/aggregate objects within a list java

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

I have a custom type which looks like this:

```
public class SampleObject {
    private UUID id;
    private List<ValueObject> values;
    
    // getters, all-args constructor, etc.
}
```

The `ValueObject` just contains some Strings.

And I have a `List` of `SampleObject`s `payload`. Within that list, there are several objects with the **same** `id` but different values in the `List<ValueObject>`.

What I want to archive is to merge all objects with the same `id` and add all the different lists of the `ValueObject`s in one merged object.

At the end, I need again a list of `SampleObject`s.

What I tried is the following:

```
List<SampleObject> payload = // initializing the List

payload.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SampleObject::getId));
```

But this returns a `Map` of `List` of `SampleObject`s.
And I don't know how to merge then the objects under the value of this Map.

Comment: I tried to summerize it again.

Comment: So you have a list of `SampleObject`s `payload` and you want to collect `ValueObject`s that are contained in the lists corresponding to the same `id` into a single `List`, and create a new `SampleObject` based on each aggregated `List`, right? And the result should be of type `List<SampleObject>` ?

Comment: You forget to provide the field name for List<ValueObject> in the `SampleObject`.

Comment: The ValueObject just contains some strings. 
Yes, within the List<SampleObject> are entities that have the same id but different ValueObject. As ValueObject is a list, I want to merge all enteries that have the same id to one SampleObject, this object should contain all ValueObjects of the duplicates. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`Collectors.flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector))

In order to combine together and store into a single list all the `ValueObject`s that correspond to the same `id` you can use Collector `flatMapping()`, which expects a *function* that produces a Stream from the element (*similarly to* `flatMap()` *operation*) and a downstream Collector which tells how the new elements produced by the *function* need to be stored.

A combination of Collectors `groupingBy()` and `flatMapping()` would give you a map of type `Map<UUID, List<ValueObject>>`. To produce a `List` of `SampleObject`s out of it, you can create a stream map entries, transform each entry into a `SampleObject` and then collect the elements into a List.

That's how implementation might look like:

```
List<SampleObject> payload = // initializing the list
    
List<SampleObject> mergedData = payload.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // intermediate Map<UUID, List<ValueObject>>
        SampleObject::getId,
        Collectors.flatMapping(
            sampleObject -> sampleObject.getValues().stream(),
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new SampleObject(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thank you again for the answer but I have a question afterwards, does this change the order of the initial list?